# MS Access SQL Range and Average

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions, ms-access-2016

[Date Time] and [MFR g/10min] are fields from [In process analysis result] table. I am supposed to find the "Range (Max-Min) of [MFR g/10min] per day" and "Average of [MFR g/10min]".
A day is defined as "Previous Day" 18:00:00 to "Today" 17:59:00.

```
SELECT [In process analysis result].[Date Time], Format([In process analysis result].[Date Time],"dd/mmm/yy") AS [Extracted Date], Format([In process analysis result].[Date Time],"hh:nn:ss") AS [Extracted Time], IIf([Extracted Time]<"18:00:00",DateAdd("d",-1,[Extracted Date]),[Extracted Date]) AS [New Date], [In process analysis result].[MFR g/10min]
FROM [In process analysis result];
```

I extracted out the [Extracted Date] and [Extracted Time]. Based on the condition that if [Extracted Time] is less than 18:00:00, it shall be considered as the previous day. The end result is [New Date].

However, from this query, I do not know how I can get the "Range (Max-Min) of [MFR g/10min] per day" and "Average of [MFR g/10min]" grouped by [New Date]. I need some help and guidance. Appreciate if anyone could help me out.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you can simplify your date calculation by taking `DateValue([Date Time])` and adding 1 day if `Hour([Date Time])` is 18 or greater. Then, use that query as a subquery in the query that does the actual calculations:

```sql
SELECT 
    EffectiveDate, 
    MAX([MFR g/10min]) - MIN([MFR g/10min]) AS DailyRange, 
    AVG([MFR g/10min]) AS DailyAverage 
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            DateAdd("d", IIf(Hour([Date Time]) < 18, 0, 1), DateValue([Date Time])) AS EffectiveDate, 
            [MFR g/10min] 
        FROM [In process analysis result]
    )
GROUP BY EffectiveDate
```